# SQL: Working out percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a proc that returns

```
|On time: 1 of 45  |1 |
|Over due: 44 of 45|44|
```

My Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_TargetStatus]
AS
BEGIN
       --Try
    Declare @OnTime float
    Declare @Overdue float
    Declare @AllON float
    Declare @AllOV float
    Declare @AnswON float
    Declare @AnswOV float

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp1

        SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
    (
        AUD_ID BIGINT,
        RowCounter BIGINT,
        DistinctCounter BIGINT,
        NACounter BIGINT,
        Total BIGINT,
        [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] 
    --TRY 2 
    Set @OnTime = (Select Count([Status])
    From #tmp1
    Where [Status] = 'OPEN')

    Set @AllON = (SELECT COUNT([Status])
    From #tmp1)

    SET @AnswON  = @OnTime/@AnswON

    Set @Overdue = (Select Count([Status])
    From #tmp1
    Where [Status] = 'CLOSED')

    Set @AllOV = (SELECT COUNT([Status])
    From #tmp1)

    SET @AnswOV  = @Overdue/@AllOV
       --TRY 2

    DECLARE @Total AS INT

    SELECT @Total = COUNT(*)
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))
            THEN 'Over Due'
            ELSE 'On Time' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t1.[Status] in ('Closed','Open')) DER 

    DECLARE @TotalTEST Float
    DECLARE @OPEN Float
    DECLARE @CLOSED FLOAT
    DECLARE @PERC FLOAT 

    SELECT ([Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + ' of ' + CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(255))) AS TargetStatus, COUNT(*)/@Total AS [Count]
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))
            THEN 'Over Due: '
            ELSE 'On Time: ' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t1.[Status] in ('Closed','Open')) DER
    GROUP BY [Target Status]

END 
GO
```

I've tried stuff like:

```
DECLARE @TotalTEST Float
DECLARE @OPEN Float
DECLARE @CLOSED FLOAT
DECLARE @PERC FLOAT 

Set @TotalTEST = (Select Count(*)from #tmp1)    
   PRint @TotalTEST
   SET @OPEN = (SELECT COUNT(*)from #tmp1 Where [Status] = 'OPEN')
   PRINT @OPEN
   SET @CLOSED = (SELECT COUNT(*)from #tmp1 Where [Status] = 'Closed' AND )
   PRINT @CLOSED
```

The percentage should(i think) be in this line `AS TargetStatus, *COUNT(*)/@Total* AS [Count]`
The outcome should be something like;

```
|On time:  1 of 45 |0.02| (Roughly)
|Over due: 44 of 45|0.98|
```

The code is messy but I've tried just divide with total, I've tried that try2 part to declare and then do something but fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide two integers, you'll always get 0.

Try this approach:

```
declare @x int  
declare @y int
set @x=1
set @y=45
select round(cast(@x as Float)/(CAST(@y as float)),2)
```

Basically, you need to work with floats or decimals

```
AS TargetStatus, cast( COUNT(*) as float)/cast(@Total as float) AS totPct
```

Comment: You don't need to, the code is only an example to show how integer division returns 0.   The only thing you need is to cast your values as the second code fragment shows

Answer (score 1):

Try `CAST((CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / CAST(@Total AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS [Count]` in your `COUNT(*)/@Total* AS [Count]`